# i want to display the order details after the customer has completed payment through pay pal

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal for the shopping cart

The code works fine. after payment when it comes to return URL, i want to display an order summary to customer.

can someone guide me on fetching the order_amt, transactionid, and displaying the same on the page?

Comment: if there is a solution already posted in another thread, can anyone post the link .... ?

Answer (score 0):

Use PayPal's PDT and IPN services.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables